# Changing component's URLs

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, url

I downloaded a component that when installed and activated, like every module sets it's URL to something like: www.mydomain.com/component/componentname/?parameters

So the question is: how can I change the **componentname** in the URL? I think I have to change a lot of files, but dont know exactly which ones. thanks

Comment: Hello Bermick, welcome to JSE. In the in the sake of clearing up any confusion about the Joomla extension types, have a look here: [General Definitions](https://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_(general_definitions)), [Technical Definitions](https://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_(technical_definitions)). FYI: there is no such thing as "Module's URL" - modules are not accessible by urls.

Comment: Thanks sorry, youre right i meant component. But components do set their own URL, right?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Either change your menu name(title) from admin section, and if it doesn't works then you need to do changes in your all files like :

If your module name is *helloworld* written as **'mod_helloworld'** you need to ***replace helloworld*** with whatever name you want. For this you also need to change your module files name and module name as well and install it again.

I think this is what you need is, and if it doesn't works then please specify clearly what is need to be done.

Comment: thanks @Nehal, I think I have to change the <name> tag in the XML installation file, also the folder as you mention, and/or something else?

Comment: To be honest, the OP wrongly mention the word "module", where it should be a component. But focusing on your answer only: I can't understand what kind of answer is this that suggests to change the naming of a module and how renaming a mod_module will have any influence in urls? Even if you also wanted to mean component instead of module, your suggestion to resolve the url issue, is to rename the whole component? What kind of practices are these?

Answer (score 1):

Your component should come with set of menu items it supports. Go to the menu manager and create its menu items. The "component/componentname" part will be replaced by your menu item alias.

Comment: thanks @Nagarjun , I think that works with a lot of componentes, but with this does not, its JHotelReservation. [link](http://hoteldemo.cmsjunkie.com/index.php?extension=j-hotelreservation%20professional)